# How do memory booster/optimizer work?

Tags: android

I found several applications in android to release memory used by other applications and to improve RAM. I am unable to understand how does those application works. How to release memory consumed by other applications?

Comment: @Down voters- Please mention the reason for down voting. which will help to know the problem in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Memory boost apps tend to kill the least recently used apps that are still running in the background. Because killing those apps means more memory for the running apps.

But the tricky part is to NOT kill the apps that are a part of the OS, As the OS will run them again and it might take more memory to load them again.